# "java.net.UnknownHostException: s3.amazonaws.com" when starting the game

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When trying to start Minecraft this evening on my mac I got the following:

```
Bootstrap (v5)
Current time is Jun 2, 2015 8:15:38 PM
System.getProperty('os.name') == 'Mac OS X'
System.getProperty('os.version') == '10.10.3'
System.getProperty('os.arch') == 'x86_64'
System.getProperty('java.version') == '1.6.0_65'
System.getProperty('java.vendor') == 'Apple Inc.'
System.getProperty('sun.arch.data.model') == '64'

Looking for update
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma
Exception: java.net.UnknownHostException: s3.amazonaws.com
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 2/10)
Exception: java.net.UnknownHostException: s3.amazonaws.com
Downloading: LINK REMOVED (try 3/10)
Exception: java.net.UnknownHostException: s3.amazonaws.com
Downloading: LINK REMOVED  (try 4/10)
Exception: java.net.UnknownHostException: s3.amazonaws.com
Downloading: LINK REMOVED  (try 5/10)
Exception: java.net.UnknownHostException: s3.amazonaws.com
Downloading: LINK REMOVED  (try 6/10)
Exception: java.net.UnknownHostException: s3.amazonaws.com
Downloading: LINK REMOVED  (try 7/10)
Exception: java.net.UnknownHostException: s3.amazonaws.com
Downloading: LINK REMOVED  (try 8/10)
Exception: java.net.UnknownHostException: s3.amazonaws.com
Downloading: LINK REMOVED  (try 9/10)
Exception: java.net.UnknownHostException: s3.amazonaws.com
Downloading: LINK REMOVED  (try 10/10)
Exception: java.net.UnknownHostException: s3.amazonaws.com

Unable to download remote file. Check your internet connection/proxy settings.
Didn't find an update in time.
Reversing LZMA on /Users/sam00cleveland/Library/Application Support/minecraft/launcher.pack.lzma to /Users/sam00cleveland/Library/Application Support/minecraft/launcher.pack
FATAL ERROR: net.minecraft.bootstrap.FatalBootstrapError: Unable to un-lzma: LZMA.LzmaException: LZMA : Data Error
    at net.minecraft.bootstrap.Bootstrap.unpack(Bootstrap.java:146)
    at net.minecraft.bootstrap.Bootstrap.execute(Bootstrap.java:123)
    at net.minecraft.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:381)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at apple.launcher.LaunchRunner.run(LaunchRunner.java:116)
    at apple.launcher.LaunchRunner.callMain(LaunchRunner.java:51)
    at apple.launcher.JavaApplicationLauncher.launch(JavaApplicationLauncher.java:52)


Please fix the error and restart.
```

<sup>I had to remove the links in the above text as I cannot post more than 2 links...</sup>

I copied the link into safari and I could download the file if I removed the `https` up front.

Comment: Has the game worked before on your comp? If yes, did this exact version work? Have you tried reinstalling Minecraft? Also, you should definitely update your java. Java 6 is very outdated.

Comment: hiya, yes this version used to work just fine. i work on a gas rig so updates are a bit hard, will see what i can do :), I used to be able to play it in offline mode....

Comment: just updated java, still no joy :(

Comment: also just downloaded the game again, no joy, do i need to delete the old one first ?, where are my games saved ?

Comment: Your Minecraft is stored in `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft` (IIRC Cmd-G opens up a go-to window in the Finder). In there, I suggest deleting everything except `saves`, `resourcepacks` and `launcherprofiles.json` (unless you don't care about those, respectively). Afterwards, the Launcher re-downloads the game entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I see two errors here:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: s3.amazonaws.com
```

Which means that your computer may not be connected to the internet. As it says, check your connection, proxy or any VPNs that you may be using.

```
net.minecraft.bootstrap.FatalBootstrapError: Unable to un-lzma: LZMA.LzmaException: LZMA : Data Error
```

Which means that an external library, handling the extraction (decompression) of the LZMA format encountered an error. As for which error - Your file was incorrectly formatted.
As for fixing it, you [may want to consider reinstalling your entire Minecraft installation (delete your `.minecraft` folder)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/221997/75275) as your initial Minecraft Launcher package was incorrectly downloaded.